# Problem with magic link in iOS when opening within mobile in-app browser

Tags: ios, authorization, local-storage, access-token

So the usual flow for magic link is:

1. User clicks on the link in their email (e.g. www.domain.com/auth/:token)
2. Page is opened in the email’s in-app browser.
3. Token is stored in the in-app browser’s local storage and token is removed from the URL (either by redirection or some other method).
4. User is logged-in (in the in-app browser).

The problem happens if the user then clicks the “Open this app in Safari” (or another browser) in a mobile's in-app browser. The user will be logged-out since the local storage state is not carried over and the token was already removed from URL parameter. Unless the token is present as a query / parameter on every page URL which is unsecure and defeats the purpose of using local storage.

What is the best solution for this use case without providing a typical login flow (username/pw)? (Or is that the only way?) Seems like you cannot browse any app in iOS using a magic link via an actual browser app since the magic link will always come from your email app (and hence, will always be opened using the in-app browser).

Comment: What is email’s in-app browser in your case?

Comment: Did you setup [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content)  between your server and your app?

Answer (score 0):

To use a magic link in order to open your App from an anchor clicked into an email client, you need definitely to setup [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content).

That said, things are not always that simple. In some circumstances Universal Links won't work and will open directly into some in-app browsers instead opening your app, this occurs sometimes with the SafariViewController embedded into email clients as you noticed.

So what to do to make it work in all cases?

As you know an Universal Link should open your app if it is installed, but it should *also* open a fallback web-page in any other circumstances when your app cannot be opened. This is where you will make it bulletproof: on the fallback web-page make sure you put an obvious button with a "safety" second/backup Universal Link that will do the exact same action into your app.

It will work because if your Universal Link fails to open directly from the email client and opens a browser window by mistake, it will most probably open your app when triggered from the in-app browser fallback web-page.

At the end, you might want to focus and put an extra effort to setup a very nice design for your fallback web page, making it look like your app, to provide a good UX so that your users may not even notice that they went thru an extra-step…

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat with our webapp's passwordless login authentication.  Did you end up using Universal Links to successfully overcome the issue?